# How to display vertical lines of varying height using css/html?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a clean way to display vertical color bars that are bottom-aligned. The current implementation adjusts the height using `font-size` which is hacky & results in vertically-centered bars.

HTML:

```
<div id="barChart">
{% for bar in bars %}
    <div class="bar" style="border-left-color:{{color}};font-size:{{barHeight}}">.</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar{
    color:transparent;
    display:inline;
}
```

How can I display vertical colored bars of varying height side by side & `bottom-aligned` using only CSS & HTML?

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/donpeat/n4z964oj/2/).

Comment: Do you have a codpen or jsfiddle to run?

Comment: @demogorgon.net see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something with `display: inline-block` this allows you to set a `height` and `width` like a block element, but still be flowed like an `inline`. This requires a few small changes, rather than using the `border-color` you'll now use the `background-color` and if you want some spacing between the bars you'd use a `margin`, but the `margin` is optional.

The trick here is the `vertical-align: bottom` which tells the browser to align the items on the bottom of the container.

```css
#barChart {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.bar {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 0px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="barChart">
  <div class="bar" style="background-color:lightblue;height:150px"> </div>
  <div class="bar" style="background-color:lightgreen;height:100px"> </div>
  <div class="bar" style="background-color:salmon;height:50px"> </div>
  <div class="bar" style="background-color:lightblue;height:150px"> </div>
  <div class="bar" style="background-color:lightgreen;height:110px"> </div>
  <div class="bar" style="background-color:salmon;height:100px"> </div>
</div>
```